# Templating for Structures

Tags: structure

I can't find anything in the Craft 3 docs that explains templating for a structure entry. What I want to do is show level 1 entries with their associated level 2 entries in a simple list type organization.

I was able to do that with Craft 2 by using `{% set subItems = entry.children %}` where entry was set to level 1 entries, but that does not work.

I can't figure out how to associate levels with parents/children. Am I missing something in the docs? Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1):

Nevermind - had a typo in my template code. Using "descendantOf" works as advertised!

Comment: Feel free to post your code and mark your answer to help others.